# Date function - Error in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a members table with field DataNa type date.

I would like to make a query like:

```
Select DateDiff (year, datana, dateserial (year,12,31)) as years, ....
from members ... etc ...
```

Year is a parametric value. But the system tells me that DateSerial is not a recognized value of default function name.

I also tried to do:

```
Select DateDiff (year, datana, datevalue ('31/12/' + year)) as years, ....
from members ... etc ...
```

It says it also is not a DateValue recognized default function name

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: what format is year ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, datana, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1)) years
  FROM members
```

This part

```
DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1)
```

returns last day of the current year (e.g. `2013-12-31`)

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b74e8/3)** demo

Comment: so why would you pick the last date of last year ? It doesn't matter which date of the year you pick when using datediff(year, x,y)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create 31-12-YYYY out from @Year int parameter for YYYY - you can do it like this:

```
DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(YY,@year - 1899,0))
```

But if you want to get difference in years between two dates - it's not important to have it 31.12, 1.1 of same year will give identical result, which you can get with:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (YEAR, datana, DATEADD(YY,@year - 1900,0))
```

[SQLFiddleDEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18144)

Comment: Tanks far all. But the DateSerial function there is SqlServer2088R2??

Comment: @Antony No. Such function does not exits. SQL Server 2012 introduced something similar with `DATEFROMPARTS` function, but in 2008R2 you have to use alternatives like shown.